# How to start specific number of workers actors during start?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I created clustered akka app  based on.

https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-distributed-workers-java/blob/master/tutorial/index.html

Is there any build in future to run specific number of actors of given type in cluster. Should I create router or there is better way ?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [Cluster-aware routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M1/java/cluster-usage.html#Cluster_Aware_Routers).

Comment: Is it possible to run actors automatically using configuration only ?